# How do I see what is using Memory?

Tags: memory-management

During the creation of a recent project the amount of memory used by Blender inflated to a massive(!) 11.8GB while attempting to render. [image]

This makes rendering on GPU unusable for me (no Titan X's here).

How do I see what is filling up this memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a Command Prompt window and navigate to the Blender application folder (e.g.  `CD "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"`)

Start Blender with the command `blender.exe --debug`.

You can now see memory usage by pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and searching for `Memory Statistics`.  This will produce a detailed list of memory usage in the command window used to open Blender:

`total memory len: 46.457 MB
peak memory len: 55.115 MB
slop memory len: 5.271 MB
 ITEMS TOTAL-MiB AVERAGE-KiB TYPE
   223 (  13.936    63.992) subsurf arena
  1498 (   8.520     5.824) BLI_Mempool Chunk
     4 (   5.881  1505.508) CDNormal
    14 (   4.996   365.455) imb_addrectImBuf
     1 (   3.000  3072.000) OCIO GPU 3D LUT
    39 (   0.923    24.242) Chunk buffer
  3779 (   0.914     0.248) PropertyRNA
     1 (   0.874   895.125) CDMloopCol
     2 (   0.750   384.016) eh buckets
...`

Comment: Wow, this is very impressive. Is there an easier way to do this? Change the .exe launch properties perhaps?

Comment: Also, for people with the steam version of Blender, you'd need to navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender

Comment: You could create a shortcut to the executable if that is preferable.

Comment: Seems like a very handy feature. Why hide it under debug mode and not allow normal users the chance to monitor their resource utilization.

Comment: Have this feature been removed from Blender 3? I open Blender in debug mode from the command prompt, but pressing Spacebar in Blender just makes it play animation as expected and the command prompt seems to be blocked while Blender is in use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AndreySokolov They changed the shortcut, it's F3 now. If it changes again you can search for "Search Menu" in your key-binding.